# android - How to handle android runtime error

Tags: android

When my application is running i am getting the android runtime error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. How to handle it?

The following is my stack trace:

```
07-05 17:34:31.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:453)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at com.ibkr.roadbrake.RB_UpcomingExits$UpcomingResultsListViewAdapter2.getView(RB_UpcomingExits.java:2232)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at com.ibkr.roadbrake.RB_UpcomingExits$8.onClick(RB_UpcomingExits.java:3921)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-05 17:34:31.937: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so... in getCount method of your adapter .... do this

```
public int getCount(){

  int size = 1;
  if(arralyst !=null){

    size = arraylist.size();
  }  
  return size;
}
```

Comment: @success_anil - Yeah, that's how software gets done these days... Instead of really fixing the problem you suggest hiding it (and even that contains a bug, because to be correct you'd return 0 when null, not 1). The worst thing is that this will become a pattern for **naresh**. :( Please, don't do this thing again - it is more than enough of shitty developers already, please do not contribute more.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are trying to access an item in an array over it's limit. That is to say you are trying to access the 6th element in a 5-element list.

Hope that makes sense, unless you post some code I cannot help you further...

Comment: IOOBE is just a consequence, if you look deeper the stack trace you'll see that there was a click on the list row, which finaly ended up in IOOBE. In most cases it happens when there was a header added to the list but one forgot "position-1" when handling the click.

Answer (score 0):

The IndexOutOfBoundsException means that you are trying to access an element in an array (or List) which does not exist. Here an example:

```
    int[] array = {0,1,2};
    Log.v("Name", array[5]);
```

This example code tries to access the sixth element of the array, but only three elements exist.

Search your class and function in the StackTrace which cause the error and then check why you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a header or footer view in the list - don't forget to adjust the click position when getting an item in your `UpcomingResultsListViewAdapter2`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious -- explicitly accessing an index which doesn't exist -- this error commonly occurs when you are iterating over a List and within your loop, you remove an element:

```
for (Foo foo : list) {
    if (isBar(foo)) {
        list.remove(foo);
    }
}
```

The iterator doesn't know about the changes, and it can throw an exception.